# Modifying records on Yii2 Mater Slave Steup

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In our commercial app, we are using master/slave feature in database configuration and running a MSSQL(business requirement) db as the master and MySQL db as a slave. We want to do read requests from the slave(MySQL) and write requests to the master(MSSQL). We have configured a background job to copy data from master to slave.

I tried to do an update to the master and it failed since the SQL generated was having MySQL syntax but not the MSSQL syntax. **The connection is switching correctly to the master**. When I checked update() function in the db/QueryBuilder.php file,

```
public function update($table, $columns, $condition, &$params)
{

    if (($tableSchema = $this->db->getTableSchema($table)) !== null) {
        $columnSchemas = $tableSchema->columns;
    } else {
        $columnSchemas = [];
    }

    $lines = [];
    foreach ($columns as $name => $value) {
        if ($value instanceof Expression) {
            $lines[] = $this->db->quoteColumnName($name) . '=' . $value->expression;
            foreach ($value->params as $n => $v) {
                $params[$n] = $v;
            }
        } else {
            $phName = self::PARAM_PREFIX . count($params);
            $lines[] = $this->db->quoteColumnName($name) . '=' . $phName;
            $params[$phName] = !is_array($value) && isset($columnSchemas[$name]) ? $columnSchemas[$name]->dbTypecast($value) : $value;
        }
    }

    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->db->quoteTableName($table) . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $lines);
    $where = $this->buildWhere($condition, $params);
    return $where === '' ? $sql : $sql . ' ' . $where;
}
```

It seems that

```
$this->db->quoteColumnName($name)
```

always gets the MySQL format. We need to have it with MSSQL format added in the QueryBuilder class in mssql/QueryBuilder.php file. I'm bit confused on how the schema is selected in this scenario for

```
$this->db
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Sam

Comment: if you are using advanced template chow your app/config/main.php  or main-local  .. If you are using basic show config/db.php

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using a single database connection .. could be you need a duoble database connect  each of them related to the proper db

eg: db1 for mysql and db2 for mssql

```
return [
  'components' => [
      'db1' => [
          'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
          'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1mysql_name', 
          'username' => 'db1username',
          'password' => 'db1password',
      ],
      'db2' => [
          'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
          'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=your.ip.address.here;Database=db2msssql_name', // change  your.ip.address.here with a proper if 
          'username' => 'db2username',
          'password' => 'db2password',
      ],
  ],
```

and then use proper connect to the right db

```
Yii::$app->db1;

Yii::$app->db2;
```